# How do I delete the printed text in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have been working on an application lately but i can't seem to find how to, off the click of a button, delete printed text in Python whilst using the Tkinter interface. I have provided the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text
import os

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("App Launcher")
root.iconbitmap('C:/Users/noahc/Documents/Programming/AppLauncher/icon.ico')
root.resizable(0,0)

apps = []

if os.path.isfile('save.txt'):
    with open('save.txt','r') as f:
        tempApps = f.read()
        tempApps = tempApps.split(',')
        apps = tempApps
        apps = [x for x in tempApps if x.strip()]


def addApp():

    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select File", filetypes=(("Executables","*.exe"), ("All Files", "*.*")))\

    apps.append(filename)
    print(filename)
    for app in apps:
        label = tk.Label(frame, text=app, bg="gray")
        label.pack()

def runApps():
    for app in apps:
        os.startfile(app)

def resetList():
    os.remove("save.txt")


canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="gray")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

openFile = tk.Button(root, text="Open File", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=addApp)
openFile.pack()

runApps = tk.Button(root, text="Run Apps", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=runApps)
runApps.pack()

resetList = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=resetList)
resetList.pack()




for app in apps:
    label = tk.Label(frame, text=app)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()


with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
    for app in apps:
        f.write(app + ',')
```

If anyone can tell me a way to delete the filename, which is printed, off the click of a button, I would be extremely grateful

Thanks,
nozzypozzy

Comment: Hello can you clarify what you mean by delete the filename printed. Do you mean delete from the filesystem?

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle, I was trying to find out how to delete the filename which is printed when the application has opened the **.exe** file which would be selected. I have since reached a resolution, as stated above, but thanks for your attempt to help me with such problem.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
text.delete(1.0,END)
```

Comment: I have tried that piece of code but that apparently only applies to the terminal. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: self.text.set("Test") -------

self.text.set("Text updated")

Answer (score 0):

The code below seemed to have worked:

```
def resetList():
os.remove("save.txt")

for widget in frame.winfo_children():
    widget.destroy()
```

Also I would like to give a big thanks to all that have attempted to help.